# how to update nodes inside other nodes in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

***Context***
Hello, I am trying to update an element of a node in firebase with android, the problem is that as seen in the structure of my database,
[image: Database]
I have a node called "comment" and within it another node with a post id and inside the Post ID node is the comment ID.

***issue***

I do not know how I can update all the nodes that meet certain encodings, since I cannot put an exact path since this would only update one node and I want to update all the nodes that meet the condition of the query as seen in the code.

```
final DatabaseReference CommentDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comment");
Query quersy = CommentDB.orderByChild("uname").equalTo(currentUsers.getDisplayName());
quersy.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String key = ds.getKey();
            HashMap<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
            maps.put("uimg", ""+mUri);
            sd.child(key).updateChildren(maps);
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. Also: this seems completely unrelated to jQuery, which is a JavaScript library. Please read the description for each tag you add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `uname` is nested under two dynamic levels. Firebase Realtime Database can only order/filter on values that are at a fixed path under one dynamic level.

So you will have to either change data structure to be a flat list under `/Comment` or read all data under `/Comment` and filter client-side.

```
final DatabaseReference commentDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comment");
commentDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot level1Snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            for(DataSnapshot level2Snapshot : level1Snapshot.getChildren()){
                if (currentUsers.getDisplayName().equals(level2Snapshot.child("uname").getValue(String.class)) {
                    Log.i("Firebase", "Updating "+level1Snapshot.getKey()+"/"+level2Snapshot.getKey());
                    level2Snapshot.getRef().child("uimg").setValue(mUri);
                }    
            }    
        }
    }
    ...
```